# Long operations in guice bean initialization

Tags: java, inversion-of-control, guice, ioc-container

I am writing an application using guice and one question came to my mind about proper bean initialisation.

The goal is the following: *There is a singleton configuration bean that should contain information pulled from the file*.

At the moment I have two options:

1. First is to create a method `init()` with an `@Inject` annotation that will read file content and initialise the bean
2. Second option is to put information inside the bean *after* the bean was initialised.

The question is whether it is a good practice to execute time-consuming operations when bean is being initialised?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) for this bean. Don't use an `init()` method. Having an `init()` method that needs to be called after it's instantiated is a form of [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). Use a [Provider](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProviderBindings) to call this bean factory. And finally, bind the bean to the provider and make it a singleton (or an [eager singleton](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes#eager-singletons)).

There is a balance between what should be loaded eagerly and what's loaded lazily. The only time I would eagerly load something is if it takes so long that it dramatically compromises performance. Having everything eagerly loaded upfront can hinder development productivity (It's not productive for an application to take 5-minutes to startup. In some cases you need to restart frequently).

**Steps**

1. Create Your Bean Factory (constructs your bean)
2. Create A Provider that calls the Bean Factory (provides your bean to guice)
3. In your module, bind the bean's key to the provider and make it a singleton (or eager singleton).

*Note: you could put your factory logic directly in the provider, but then your logic is bound to guice.*

Comment: I would like to add one point after studying guice documentation, that for I/O operations it is better to use [ThrowingProviders](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BeCarefulAboutIoInProviders).